# Django - How to allow users to enter decimals in scientific notation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal, scientific-notation

I want users to be able to enter a standard decimal value like 1.51 or enter a value in scientific notation like 4.08E+13.

I set up a decimal field in my model but when I try to enter the above example I get this validation message:

"Ensure that there are no more than 3 decimal places."

Side note:

I did notice that Python already supports this format:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> print Decimal("4.08E+13")
4.08E+13
```

So maybe it won't be too hard to set something up in Django?

Comment: Did you intentionally avoid reading this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField.decimal_places?

Comment: 4.08E+13 has two decimal places, I'm allowing up to three.  Did you intentionally avoid reading my question!

Comment: 4.08E+13 doesn't have *any* decimal places.  It does, however, have 14 digits.

Comment: @Greg - correct me if I'm wrong, but didn't that link provided by S. Lott directly takes you to how to set up Django to allow for *X* number of decimal places and maximum number of digits?

Comment: I followed those instructions.  I've tried all manner of decimal_places and max_digit values.  If I bump them up really high it seems to accept the value but then gives me this error: "quantize result has too many digits for current context"

Comment: @Greg: Please provide a specific setting and a specific error message.    "all manner of" means that we can't guess what combinations you've actually tried.  The instructions are quite simple and your data (4.08E+13) doesn't match your requirements well at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Django bug, DecimalField.validate() is wrong for positive exponents:

```
>>> from django.forms import DecimalField
>>> f = DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
>>> f.validate(Decimal('1E+2'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValidationError: [u'Ensure that there are no more than 1 decimal places.']
```

You may want to [file a bug](http://code.djangoproject.com/newticket).

Comment: Thanks.  In the meantime I guess I should write my own custom model field?

Comment: So much for submitting a bug.  I got "Submission rejected as potential spam (BlogSpam says content is spam (badip:state/blacklist.d/127.0.0.1))"

Comment: If you write a nice patch (include a testcase!) and a clear bug report you may have luck and get it committed quickly. However, if you don't want to use trunk or cannot wait I'd recommend subclassing DecimalField and overwriting validate().

Comment: You'll have to register to bypass the spam filter.

Comment: Question about subclassing.  I want to override models.DecimalField but the only DecimalField class I'm seeing is in forms/fields.py.  Is that actually what I want?

Comment: You have to subclass forms.DecimalField to work around the bug in validate. Then use that subclass in your forms. If you want to use that automatically for modelforms, subclass models.DecimalField and implement formfield().